# Reversing direction of connections (edges) in igraph using python

Tags: python, igraph

How does one reverse the direction of connections in igraph using python? I am using the layout_fruchterman_reingold layout. Thank you!

Comment: 1. Turn into an adjacency matrix 2. Transpose 3. Back to graph